# property getters and setters in python not showing all properties

Tags: python

I have declared the following class and declared `email` as a property which is initialized with property decorators.however the `__dict__` does not list `email` as the property of the object rather lists `_email`.
How is this working?

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self,first,second):
        self.first=first
        self.second=second
        self.email=first+","+second
    @property
    def email(self):
        return self._email
    @email.setter
    def email(self,e):
        self._email=e
        
a = abc("hello","world")
print(a.first)
print(a.second)
print(a.email)
print(a.__dict__)
```

Comment: The property is on the _class_, only the backing attribute is in the instance dictionary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you elaborate please

Answer (score -1):

This is what sets the attribute and hence why it shows *_email*:

```
@email.setter
def email(self,e):
    self._email=e
```

This setter function is called when you write:

```
self.email=first+","+second
```

Which is like writing:

```
email(first+","+second)
```

And then results in:

```
self._email=first+","+second
```

Lastly, when we refer to *self.email*, we are essentially calling the getter:

```
@property
def email(self):
    return self._email
```

However, when we refer to *self._email*, we are accessing the backing attribute without calling the 'getter'. This is why it makes sense to distinguish between *_email* and *email*, and why it specifies *_email* in the dict.